# How would I render a list with Mandrill template out of array passed in MERGE VARS

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

I have to make substitution with `merge_vars`.

```
{
   "key":"some key",
   "template_name":"order-confirmation",
   "template_content":[
      {
         "name":"ORDERNUMBER",
         "content":"12312312321"
      },
      {
         "name":"PRICE",
         "content":"35.10"
      },
      {
         "name":"NAME",
         "content":"Some name"
      },
      {
         "name":"PICKUPDATE",
         "content":"2013-05-10"
      },
      {
         "name":"ORDERITEMS",
         "content":[
            {
               "NUMPRODUCTS":"26",
               "PRODUCTNAME":"Milk",
               "PRODUCTPRICE":"1.35 EUR"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"SERVICENUMBER",
         "content":"12345"
      },
      {
         "name":"PICKUPPOINT",
         "content":"AAA 350"
      },
      "message":{
         "from_email":"support@support.com",
         "to":[
            {
               "email":"asdasd@asda.com"
            }
         ],
         "subject":"Subject text",
         "attachments":[

         ]
      },
      "async":false
   }
}
```

how should I make html placeholders? I did it like this but it doesn't work. 
I'm only interested in `ORDERITEMS`.

```
<tr>
 <td>*|ORDERITEMS:NUMPRODUCTS|*</td>
 <td>*|ORDERITEMS:PRODUCTNAME|*</td>
 <td>*|ORDERITEMS:PRODUCTPRICE|*</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: did you tried ***var api = new MandrillApi(ApiKey);

          
            var resultRender = api.Render(templateExample, templateContent, null);***

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know, using the normal templating engine in Mandrill, the only supported type for the `content` attribute is `string`, so there is no way to provide a structure.

Recently, (Jan 13 2015) Mandrill announced support for handlebars templates, and with that, the posibility to include arrays in the `content`.

http://blog.mandrill.com/handlebars-for-templates-and-dynamic-content.html

With this new template language it is possible to not only access sub-propertys as you need, but even loop inside arrays, and even nested do loops. (see [this comment](http://blog.mandrill.com/handlebars-for-templates-and-dynamic-content.html#comment-1812033668) on the blog post)

This is an example extracted from the blog post for doing a loop:

The merge variable or template content:

```
{
    "name": "products",
    "content": [
        {
            "img": "http://kbcdn.mandrill.com/nesting-penguin.png",
            "qty": 2,
            "sku": "PENG001",
            "name": "Penguin",
            "description": "Solid wood, hand-painted penguin nesting doll with 5 different sizes included. Limited Edition.",
            "price": "12.99",
            "ordPrice": "25.98"
        },
        {
            "img": "http://kbcdn.mandrill.com/nesting-bear.png",
            "qty": 3,
            "sku": "BBEAR001",
            "name": "Brown bear",
            "description": "Solid wood, hand-painted brown bear nesting doll. Coordinates with our entire Bear collection. Includes 6 nested sizes.",
            "price": "12.99",
            "ordPrice": "38.97"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is how to consume it in the template:

```
{{#each products}}
<tr class="item">
    <td valign="top" class="textContent">
        <img src="{{img}}" width="50" height="75" class="itemImage" />
        <h4 class="itemName">{{name}}</h4>
        <span class="contentSecondary">Qty: {{qty}} x ${{price}}/each</span><br />
        <span class="contentSecondary sku"><em>{{sku}}</em></span><br />
        <span class="contentSecondary itemDescription">{{description}}</span>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" class="textContent alignRight priceWidth">
        ${{ordPrice}}
    </td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

In your case, you could do:

```
{{#each ORDERITEMS}}
<tr>
 <td>{{NUMPRODUCTS}}*</td>
 <td>{{PRODUCTNAME}}</td>
 <td>{{PRODUCTPRICE}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: It's not working, when I sent the email, the loop was printed in the email. Template didn't execute that.

Here's what my template looks like:

```{{#each notifications}}
<tr class="item">
    <td valign="top" class="textContent">
        <img src="{{profile_picture}}" width="50" height="75" class="itemImage"/>
        <h4 class="itemName">{{name}}</h4>
    </td>
</tr>
{{/each}}```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has these same problem, and the doc solution does not work, check the field merge_language in your message json. It has to be defined to handlebars.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

10 years on and this question is still useful but here are some updates for those who might need it.

Handlebars is the way to go when trying to render a list in a mandrill / mailchimp email. The primary take away here is that to use handlebars you need to make sure you enable the "handlebars" scripting language, by default this is set to `mailchimp`.

In the API this is done by adding `merge_language` to the `message` dictionary:

```
merge_language: the merge tag language to use when evaluating merge
tags, either mailchimp or handlebars Possible values: "mailchimp" 
or "handlebars".
```

For example:

```py
response = client.messages.send_template(
    {
        "template_name": "template_name",
        "template_content": [{}], 
        "message": {
            "merge_language": "handlebars",
        }
    }
)
```