# Printing multidimensional arrays with Mandrill handlebars

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

All questions I can find pertaining to this topic are >4 years old, and no longer seem to be relevant. Such as [How would I render a list with Mandrill template out of array passed in MERGE VARS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605718/how-would-i-render-a-list-with-mandrill-template-out-of-array-passed-in-merge-va)

#### How can I print multidimensional arrays in a Mandrill template using handlebars?

Consider the following data structure

```
"global_merge_vars": [
    {
        "name": "items",
        "content": [
            {
                "ID": 5009,
                "Qty": 2,
                "Name": "Firefly Candle - Green Bamboo"
            }
            {
                "ID": 3544,
                "Qty": 1,
                "Name": "Aeropress Coffee Maker"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Then, in my template I have

```
<table>
    {{#each items}}
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://example.com/imgs/{{ID}}.jpg" /></td>
        <td>{{Qty}}x {{Name}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

And it always comes though empty. No content at all. I've tried `{{#each items.content}}`. I've tried `{{this.Qty}}`. I've tried every combination and every permutation thereof I can find online, but none of it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution did end being `{{#each items}}` AND `{{this.Qty}}`. Thus making the final template look like:

```
<table>
    {{#each items}}
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://example.com/imgs/{{this.ID}}.jpg" /></td>
        <td>{{this.Qty}}x {{this.Name}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```